# SQL Query Source Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables. One table has all the people, `[Pat]`, each with a unique `[PatId]`. The second table has all the insurance company information, `[Ins]`, each with a unique `[InsId]`. The third table has the patient insurance info, `[PatIns]`. In the `[PatIns]` table, some patients (also `[PatId]`) have secondary or 3rd insurance and it denoted in `[InsType]` as 1, 2, or 3. I need a SQL query that will not only join the 3 tables, but also return the data when a patient has secondary or third insurance. So far I have:

```
SELECT * 

FROM [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPat], 

[XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxIns],

[XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns]

[XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] AS INS2,

[XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] AS INS3 

WHERE [xrxPat].[PatId]=[xrxPatIns].[PatId] 

AND [xrxPatIns].[PatId] = INS2.[PatId] 

AND [xrxPatIns].[PatId] = INS3.[PatId]

AND [xrxIns].[RecNo]=[xrxPatIns].[InsId] 

AND [xrxPatIns].[InsType]=1

AND INS2.[InsType]=2 

AND INS3.[InsType]=3;
```

Problem is this only returns patients with 3 insurances. I would like to return all the patients and null values for tables INS2 and/or INS3 if the patient only has 1 insurance. 
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this could be done in the where clause, you're best off changing to using explicit joins, as that makes the code easier to read as well.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPat]
INNER JOIN [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxIns]
    ON [xrxPat].[PatId] = [xrxIns].[PatId]
INNER JOIN [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns]
    ON [xrxIns].[RecNo] = [xrxPatIns].[InsId]
    AND [xrxPatIns].[InsType] = 1
LEFT JOIN [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] AS INS2
    ON [xrxIns].[RecNo] = INS2.[PatId]
    AND INS2.[InsType] = 2
LEFT JOIN [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] AS INS3
    ON [xrxIns].[RecNo] = INS3.[PatId]
    AND INS3.[InsType] = 3;
```

Comment: will this correctly handle all 3 cases: the customer has 1, 2, or 3 policies?

Comment: Running the query I get: 
'The multi-part identifier "xrxPatIns.PatId" could not be bound.'

Not that familiar with SQL, how I fix it?

Comment: Line 5 should be:     ON [xrxPat].[PatId] = [xrxIns].[PatId]

Answer (score 0):

Use the JOIN notation instead of commas. Then make them LEFT JOINs.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] WHERE [InsType]=1) AS INS1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] WHERE [InsType]=2) AS INS2
ON INS1.[PatId] = INS2.[PatId]
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM [XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPatIns] WHERE [InsType]=3) AS INS3
ON INS1.[PatId] = INS3.[PatId]
JOIN
[XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxPat]
ON [xrxPat].[PatId]=INS1.[PatId] 
JOIN
[XEREX_TEST].[dbo].[xrxIns]
ON [xrxIns].[RecNo]=INS1.[InsId] 
;
```